# c++ MFC execute three consecutive processes with a progress bar

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, progress-bar, createprocess

Thank you for reading my post.
Here is my problem:

I need to install (run) three programs one after the other: P1, P2 and P3.

If P1 is not installed properly, P2 installation will fail.

And if P1 and P2 are not installed properly, P3 installation will fail.

In addition to this, I need a dialog box which displays a progress bar and shows the progress of the installation:

- after P1 is installed, the progress bar will be set to 1/3 full,
- after P2 is installed, the progress bar will be set to 2/3 full,
- after P3 is installed, the progress bar will be set to 3/3 full.

I am using C++ and MFC.

I am asking myself whether I should:

- create one process for P1, one process for P2 and one process for P3 using the "CreateProcess()" function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). 
  I have already tried this option but I am having a hard time making sure P1 installation is finished before P2 installation starts and P1 and P2 are installed before P3 installation starts and to synchronize the progress bar with these installations...
- having X threads: one main thread which basically shows the progress bar, one (or several threads) to install P1, P2 and P3.

So I have two problems to solve:

- launching three installations one after the other,
- having a dialog box which shows the progress of the installation.

Can you tell me how you would do that?

Another question I'm asking myself is whether a thread can be used to launch a command like "msiexec"?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog box, after creating Pn (n = 1, 2, 3), start a timer which periodically calls [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx) until the exit code is not `STILL_ACTIVE` (259); verify that the exit code is not an error, update the progress bar and start the next process.

Comment: Hello Edward and thank you for your answer.
I chose the second option I mentioned: in addition to the main thread I created a second thread. In this second thread, the three CreateProcess() functions are invoked.
After each create process, I call the function WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
Is this function not 100% reliable?
Do I have to call the GetExitCodeProcess() function in addition to this?
Thanks and best regards.

Comment: You can use `WaitForSingleObject`, only then your dialog will "hang" until the process is finished; the alternative would be to set up a timer (say every 1-2 seconds) and check `GetExitCodeProcess` in the timer function, in that way you won't hang the dialog box UI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The dialog contains a progress bar.
It also contains a "start" button, a "cancel" button and the dialog top-right "close" button.
The purpose of this dialog box is: first, to start the execution of the processes and then, to show the progress of their execution.
I can click the "cancel" button or the "close" button and have the dialog be closed before all the processes have completed successfully.

Comment: .../... If I close the dialog after the second process has been started : 1) the dialog closes itself, 2) the second process terminates (even after the dialog is closed) (I know it because the process emits a beeps when it ends) 3) the third process is not executed at all.
So I am wondering what you mean when you say that the dialog "hangs"... Thank you.

Comment: From what I understand about `WaitForSingleObject`, the cancel button will not do anything until the corresponding process has finished and the WaitForSingleObject function returns

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I only need the dialog to display a progress bar, I removed all the buttons so that the dialog can't be interrupted by the user directly (it only contains the progress bar). It pretty much suits me that way... Best regards.